# Start Debugging session in NetBeans

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans

I am trying to get familiar with NetBeans Debugging environment, for c/c++ applications. I followed the procedures on https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/debugging.html 
but every time I want to start debugging by : Debug>Debug Project Ctrl+f5 , i get a bothering error as this:

GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return -1,073,741,515

any Idea what I should do ?! thanks

Comment: Quick conversion of that return value to hex is `0xc0000135`, which is a Windows `HRESULT` for "DLL not found" - sounds like an installation issue with GDB or whatever installed it.

Comment: Thanks Drew, You think re-installing the GCC with help ?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: another question, for downloading the gdb, should I delete the gcc and download everything again ? since gdb came as a package bundled with gcc !